# GNOME-like workspaces for Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, gnome, workspace

I worked a lot in the GNOME environment in Ubuntu and really liked it.
But, I had to move to Windows due to some reasons.

Is there any program that can allow to me to switch between workspaces like I did in GNOME?

Comment: This is now default in windows 10, the icon is next to corona.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Microsoft Sysinternals [Desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881)

Comment: This is a pretty nice solution

Comment: Now if only the Windows key in Win8.1 wouldn't catapult you back to the first desktop :( This is my primary way of launching any application via the keyboard.

Comment: Actually, it's pretty terrible. It's always launching stuff, like browser windows, back on the original desktop.

Comment: @WilliamGunn Windows 10. No more problems..

Comment: Also found it here: http://www.howtogeek.com/195962/unlock-virtual-desktops-on-windows-7-or-8-with-this-microsoft-tool - very useful :)

Comment: Nice. Works for me too!

Comment: coming from linux, I found it less than ideal that I have only limited options for the hotkeys I am allowed to use. (ctrl+alt+ Functions keys or numbers).

Answer (score 8):

I've used VirtuaWin with good results ...

http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/

"VirtuaWin is a freely distributed program and is licensed under the GNU General Public License."

Comment: Yes! Since Sysinternals Desktops has no solution for running multiple instances of Firefox this is what I would also suggest. Furthermore it has more config opportunities. A single contra to mention: Desktop switching appear to be a little slower.

Answer (score 6):

Dexpot is a versatile desktop manager for Windows that is free for personal use. Most versions of Windows are supported. Through plugins it's possible to get Compiz-like effects like the rotating cube. I've had good results with it.

http://www.dexpot.de/?id=download

Comment: Dexpot is the closest alternative functionally-wise, because it provides the Exposé-like features ["windows catalog" (both per-application or for all application) and "fullscreen previsualization"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43mD7OaXLH0).